# How do I delay a function executing for each element in an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a Simon game and I am trying to delay the iteration of a for loop such that there is a gap between each call of a function. I want there to be a delay between the program's lighting up of the different wedges on the simon board. I am having a hard time understanding how to use a setInterval and would love some help.

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/MindfulBell/pen/LpwGZP

```
function lightUp(move){
switch (move) {
  case 1:
      $(grn).css('background-color', 'lightgreen')
      setTimeout(function(){
          $(grn).css('background-color', 'green');
      }, 1500)
      break;
    case 2:
      $(red).css('background-color', 'red');
      setTimeout(function(){
          $(red).css('background-color', 'darkred');
      }, 1500)
      break;          
    case 3:
      $(yel).css('background-color', 'lightyellow');
      setTimeout(function(){
          $(yel).css('background-color', 'yellow');
      }, 1500)
      break;          
    default:
      $(blue).css('background-color', 'lightblue');
      setTimeout(function(){
          $(blue).css('background-color', 'blue');
      }, 1500)
      break;

  }
 } 

//problem is it lights everything up at the same time, not one at a time, need to figure out how to do a delay or some such...

  function simonSaysLv1(){   
    simonsMoves.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (4-1+1)) + 1)
    for (i=0; i<simonsMoves.length; i++) {
      lightUp(simonsMoves[i]);
    }      
  }
```

This does not work as it just lights up everything at the same time. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: removed "index" to be "i". Also, this is built for testing, so multiple clicks of the white div in the center is necessary to see this run with multiple values in the array.

Comment: You'll want to look into the "setTimeout" function. However, you probably will need to set up this function to be recursive in order to get your desired outcome.

Comment: Pass the timeout for `setTimeout` as parameter of `lightUp` and use this parameter instead of the fixed value `1500`

Comment: instead of having all the timeouts use a fixed value of 1500, why not just use 1500 * move ?  The first one will then get 1500, next on 3000 etc.  Will no longer execute at the same time.

Comment: What is `index` in your code? Also, the `Array` `simonsMoves` will only hold one value, so you will only get one iteration. I think you want to assign the calculated value to a `variable` and then do `i<variable`. And use `i` instead of index.

Comment: I have updated my answer and tested in your codepen. Seems to be working for me as expected.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Not sure that would work because the value for "move" will not === the index of the array. the move values will be either 1, 2, 3, or 4 to indicate which div to light up. If it was just the indeces of the array, that would make sense. But I can't figure out how to pass the indeces of the array as arguments into lightUp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `setTimeout`, like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    lightUp(simonsMoves[index]);
}, i*1000);
```

This will call the function immediately and then once every second (1000 milliseconds between).

I think something like this is what you're after:

```
function simonSaysLv1(){
    simonsMoves.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (4-1+1)) + 1);
    for (i=0; i<simonsMoves.length; i++) {
        (function(index){
            setTimeout(function(){
                lightUp(simonsMoves[index]);
            }, 1500*index);
        })(i);
    }      
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbgWwx)

**Alternative way**

As I'm currently taking requests, and for people with wooden computers not able to handle 30 simultaneous `setTimeout`, this is how it can be done with a recursive function:

```
function simonSaysLv1(){   
    simonsMoves.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (4-1+1)) + 1);
    doSimonMove(0);    
}

function doSimonMove(index){
    if(index < simonsMoves.length){
        lightUp(simonsMoves[index]);
        setTimeout(function(){
            doSimonMove(index + 1);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avedKb)

Comment: Yes, the first would execute directly, the second after 1 second, the third after 2 seconds, etc... The for-loop does not stop.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Btw 1, 2, 3... Seem pretty linear to me, not exponential.

Comment: I doubt anyone plays Simon says that long :).

Comment: @DelightedD0D: What does “efficient” mean?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara performing or functioning in the best possible manner with the least waste of time and effort;

Comment: @DelightedD0D: So what’s being wasted here? Have you measured timers to be excessively expensive to create in parallel?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Would you say that this is a fair comparison (dead serious non cynical question)? http://jsperf.com/wooden-pc-test , if so, using multiple timers is 79% slower.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: You’d have to make it an asynchronous test since `setTimeout` is an asynchronous function, but being `setTimeout`, I don’t think you can really benchmark it like that (everything’s going to take approximately the amount of time you pass in). Maybe measure… memory usage? Battery life? Even so, to get noticeable results, you’d have to push the number of timers beyond reality, at which point the benchmark doesn’t really matter. So I guess we just take “premature optimization is the root of all evil” to heart here and pick whichever one the asker finds most comprehensible.

Comment: @Arg0n Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- add
   `.sim-button { cursor: pointer; }`
   `#inner-circle { cursor: pointer; }`
   to your CSS *(Simon's button will now look clickable!)*

Now, about your problem:

- The `setTimeOut()` has the same `1500`ms delay without any multiplier
  to order them. That's why they all pop up at the same time. 
  inside `function simonSaysLv1(){` pass `i+1`as a **counter** in `lightUp(simonsMoves[i], i+1);`.
  recieve it (`order`) as a param in `function lightUp(move, order){`
  change your `setTimeOut` from `1500` to `1500 * order`
- Javascript's/jQuery's event trigger method is **asynchronous** so `setTimeOut()` will be needed for both *light and regular* color. **Do:**

```js
case 1:
          setTimeout(function(){
              $(grn).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
          }, 1500 * order);
          setTimeout(function(){
              $(grn).css('background-color', 'green');
          }, 2000 * order);
          break;
```

and similar to every other color.

- Lastly: remember to add `;` in all appropriate places. *Many are missing*. Code is running perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a recursive function would be better suited to this situation. Something along the lines of:

```
function lightUp(simonsMoves,currentIndex){
    // do whatever you need to to show the light here
    // then wait one second and call the function again passing the next index
    setTimeout(function(){
         lightUp(simonsMoves, currentIndex+1);
    },1000);
}


// start it off by calling `lightUp` passing the array of moves and the starting index
lightUp(simonsMoves,0);
```